# Construct Assimp bone hierarchy, beginning at the root

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, assimp

I am using Assimp.net to import animated .dae files into my OpenTK engine and struggling to establish a usable hierarchal bone structure.

In the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0jb1OBw45I) I am following, the root bone, or "joint", contains a list of it's children joints, and those a list of their children and so on.

Assimp returns each imported `Mesh` object with a list of `Bone` objects, emcapsuling the bone's `Name`, `OffsetMatrix` and `VertexWeights`, but nothing about it's children or parent bones.

The `Scene`, which contains the `Mesh`, does have a list of total `nodes` (some of which are bones) and these do have a `parentName` value but building the hierarchy through recursive comparison checks is getting messy quick and is far from functioning.

How can I the isolate the root bone, then it's children, then their children, etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out every node contains a *collection* of it's children called `children` of type `NodeCollection`, and from there I developed the following solution.

**To find the root bone**, iterate over every `node` in the `scene` and check if it's name is found in the `bones` list contained in the `mesh`, then if that `node` has a parent name which isn't in the `bones` list then it must be the root bone.

**To build the bone hierarchy**, get the `children` from that "root bone" node found above, then find the matching name within the meshes`bones` list, and from there extract the required vertex weights and offset matrix. Next, recursively search through the children of those children using the same method as above: iterating over each `node` in the scene until the matching `bone` name is found, then pull the data from the `bone` within the `bones` list, and do so reversely until there's no children left.

If there's a better way, I'd love to hear it.